# Changing python source from network to local drive

Tags: python, windows-7, anaconda

I'm using Anaconda to manage libraries for Python 3.

I have a team I work with using a network drive, but running scripts from the network drive is often very slow, so I'd like a local installation of Python as well.

I've got Anaconda installed on my local machine, but when I use `conda list` in the command prompt I still get a message that says *'packages in environment at'* and then my network drive installation location.

I have a feeling this has to do with setting the PATH variable.  How can I switch where Anaconda (and Python) is sourced from?

Answer (score 0):

*I finally got to my limit when a colleague imposed the use of 32-bit Python and I had to start switching back and forth between 32-bit and 64-bit frequently.*

---

The way I solved this - which might not be very good, but it works - is to write a one-line Windows *.bat* file:

> set PATH=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\Scripts;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda2\Library\bin

Add all the standard, unchanging stuff you have in the `PATH` variable to that line as well, or else it'll be cleared.

Then to switch back and forth quickly I just run `version.bat` from the command prompt. Pretty simple, really.